# Intellij plugin - difference between applicationservice and projectService?

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins

What is the difference between the two types of service in intellij plugin land?

The documentation for this is straight out of the 1970s, and while it mentions three different types - although it immediately before that mentions a light service (4th type), and also says that module services should not be used - it never bothers to mention why there are so many different service types, and what a use case for them would be.

https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/plugin_structure/plugin_services.html#how-to-declare-a-service

Answer (score -2):

Application, Project and Module level mimic their counterparts explained in great detail in "[Part III - Project Model](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/project_structure.html)", so their instance is "local" to their parent scope.

A "Light Service" is not another variant, but just another way of registering a service.

Comment: hm, where is application defined there?

Comment: also what do you mean "local to their parent scope"?

Comment: We've reworded the page to make it more clear:

The IntelliJ Platform offers three types of services: application level services (global singleton), project level services, and module level services. For the latter two, a separate instance of the service is created for each instance of its corresponding scope, see Project Model Introduction.